ObservableCollection Not Updating UI After Refresh in .NET MAUI
I'm developing a .NET MAUI application where I have a ClientReviewsViewModel that uses an ObservableCollection to display a list of reviews. The reviews are displayed in a CollectionView, and I'm using a RefreshView to refresh the data. The issue I'm facing is that while the data loads perfectly when the page initially loads, it does not appear after I refresh the data.
Here’s a snippet of my XAML layout:
<ActivityIndicator
    Grid.Row="0"
    IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    Color="{StaticResource Primary}"/>

<RefreshView
    Grid.Row="0"
    Command="{Binding LoadClientReviewsCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
    IsEnabled="True"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsRefreshing, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}">

    <ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
        <Grid>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ReviewsList}"
                            Margin="0,15,0,0">
                <!-- CollectionView ItemTemplate here -->
            </CollectionView>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</RefreshView>

And here’s a part of my ClientReviewsViewModel:
public partial class ClientReviewsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ReviewViewModel> ReviewsList { get; set; }
    public UserProfileViewModel ProfileUser { get; set; }
    public string UserId;
    private RoutingService routingService;
    private Repo repo;

    public ClientReviewsViewModel(Repo repo, RoutingService routingService)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.routingService = routingService;
        ReviewsList = new ObservableCollection<ReviewViewModel>();
        ProfileUser = new UserProfileViewModel();
        IndicatorTitle = "Reviews";
    }

    private void PopulateReviewsList(UserProfileViewModel profileUser)
    {
        ReviewsList.Clear();
        if (profileUser.Reviews?.Any() == true)
        {
            foreach (var review in profileUser.Reviews)
            {
                ReviewsList.Add(review);
            }
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task LoadClientReviews()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {
            PopulateReviewsList(ProfileUser);
            LastRefreshed = DateTime.Now;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Dialogs.Toast(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsRefreshing = false;
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}


Issue:
When I call LoadClientReviews, the ReviewsList is cleared and repopulated, but the UI does not anything.
Questions:
Why is the ObservableCollection not updating the UI after refreshing?
Is there anything I need to check or implement to ensure the UI reflects the changes made to the ObservableCollection?
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Try removing the ScrollView

@Jason Still same issue

Since we cannot see the code for profileUser.Reviews we do not know if it is changing. Could you confirm that it does? Have you put Trace.WriteLine in PopulateReviewsList to confirm that it is (1) being called, (2) generate the correct / changing values, (3) actually populating your ObservableCollection?

You can use the PropertyChanged method in response to the ReviewsList change, I debugged and found that it  was working fine.

Try this:
// Generates a "ReviewsList" property for you.
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<ReviewViewModel> _reviewsList = []

instead of this:
public ObservableCollection<ReviewViewModel> ReviewsList { get; set; }


« ScrollView objects should not be nested. In addition, ScrollView objects should not be nested with other controls that provide scrolling, such as CollectionView, ListView, and WebView. »
So it’s likely you have to punt the scroll view.

Still same issue

My two cents for optimizing Async calls.
Pass a IDispatcher  using Dependency injection. It is already avaliable for you.
await _dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>Toast.Make("ex.Message").Show(tokenSource.Token)).ConfigureAwait(false);

ConfigureAwait(false) is there just to boost performance.
Also do this
await _dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() => ReviewsList.Add(review));
Without this your code could crash on IOS.
As Andrew mentioned Utilize Community toolkit. It will do a lot of work for you and also minimize errors, because under the hood it uses all the best practices  plus saves a lot of time and effort for you
